# Como implementar histórico de todas as operações feitas

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso registrar todas as operações de alteração, inserção e remoção.

Até o momento fiz alguns testes, capturando o nome dos campos nos formulários que tiveram seus valores alterados (isso para casos de edição).

Estou registrando tudo na seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE operacoes_log (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  feito_por int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  tipo int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  relacao_correspondente int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  referencia_operacao_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  descricao text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
);
```

Por enquanto estou conseguindo fazer os registros das operações, mas a parte mais complicada está sendo recuperar estas informações para gerar um relatório. O sistema foi construído com laravel 5.4.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma referência ou abordagem para este tipo de implementação.

Comment: Andrei, voce pode explicar o que esta sendo complicado? voce não esta conseguindo ler a tabela `operacoes_log`?

Comment: Na verdade estou com dúvidas sobre a implementação deste tipo de caso, onde preciso manter um histórico das operações e encontrar uma forma viável de recuperar os registros que estão nesta tabela e os registros que fazem referência a está operação. Como são várias tabelas que podem ter os registros alterados fica meio inviável fazer um "if" para cada tipo.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa biblioteca https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/introduction Caso fot usar, verifique a versão recomendada para o Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca `laravel-activitylog` que foi citada no comentário:

Doc: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/introduction

Ou criar sua propria implementação usando os `Observers`:

Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers